# IPad layout issue

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, user-interface

On my iPhone, and all other iPhones, and all IOS Simulators both iPad and iPhone, my layout looks like this:[image]

However, after submitting to app store, my app got rejected, because it the page gets 'cut off' on the iPad, and is reported to look like this: [image]

These are precise but simplified images of the problem. The background is meant to be a camera view (hence fuzzy background). and the translucent box is a UIView programatically added, where the width is defined dynamically via screen width info:

```
screenSize: CGRect = UIScreen.main.bounds;
width = Int(screenSize.width)-5;
x = Int(screenSize.width/2)-width/2;
```

Please note, this has worked great on all previous updates, on all devices, and even though I made no change to this, for some reason my app has been rejected this time, with the screenshot shown.

I have tried running it on all different iPad simulators, but I was not able to reproduced the problem. My only thought is that it has something to do with orientation, however I still have no way of telling. I do have code in AppDelegate that locks app to portrait...again, its always been this way without problem.

I therefore have three questions. Firstly, what could possibly be the difference on the reviewers iPad that is not the case on the Xcode iPad simulators?

Secondly, why has this suddenly been flagged as a problem when my app has been accepted with the same UI code before?

Thirdly and most importantly, what are the possible causes/fixes?

Thank you very much.

Comment: is this app supported for IPAD and iphone ?

Comment: I only want it available for iPhone, but after talking to app review, they seem to keep trying to use it for iPad.

Comment: what is your `Devices` under `Deployment Info` in `General` tab of your project settings ?  Is it `iphone` or `ipad` or `Universal` ?

Comment: it is set to iPhone

Comment: ok try run your project in iphone 4s simulator and let me know here. this issues will display there.

Comment: okay will do now.

Comment: On iPhone 4s, it still does not reproduce issue. it works fine.

Comment: Well now try it on iPad pro 12.9 inch.

Comment: it does not reproduce on any iPad in simulator.

Comment: any possible reasons for this?

Answer (score 0):

Do following:
[image]

and do correct your autolayout. It will work. thanks

Comment: No, op want his app for iphone only! then why make it universal?

Comment: Then if your app working fine in iPhone 4 then it must work in iPad too, what constraints did you set, can you elaborate it ?

Comment: I am downloading iphone4 simulator now. Will get back to you. I do not mind if users use app on iPad, as long as it looks correct. Will setting it to universal actually fix the issue?

Comment: Now I'm not sure, but If your layouts working fine in iphone 4 then it should work in iPad too, Perhaps i can help you, if you let me know the constraints you had set for your views.

Comment: all my user interface is made programmatically. So, where would I find constraints?

Comment: Well, did you run on iPad 12.9 inch ?

Answer (score 0):

this should be your `autolayou`t issue! according to apple application submission guideline, if you are submitting app for iphone only then also your app should run fine in `ipad` also. So, check your constraints for this screen and correct if any thing wrong! and you not need to make your application `universal` as you want `iphone` only

Comment: Where do I check constraints and would am I looking for?